# Octave plotting step-by-step (!) a costfunction and a gradient descent

Tags: plot, octave

for Andrew Ng's Cousera course "machine learning" I  started to use **`Octave`**.

For the assignment on linear regression (one Variable) code is provided that creates a scatter plot of the original data with the fitted line, the bow shaped cost function  **`J( theta_0, theta_1 )`** and a contour plot.

BUT: all these plots provide only the FINAL result.

I would like to see a step-by-step plot development so as to understand better what's going on. Step-by-step means: create a figure, add first value, then second, then third, etc, until arriving at the final result.

(1) Screenshot from one lecture video: Is it possible to visualise this, adding the pink then the green, then red, etc dot?

[image: Screenshot from one lecture video: Is it possible to visualise this, i.e. adding the pink, then the green dot, then red dot, etc dot?]

(2.1) First step in searching for the correct parameters, gradient Descent Step 1

(2.2) Final step in searching for the correct parameters, gradient descent: all single steps are included

[image: (2) First step in searching for the correct parameters, i.e. gradient Descent Step 1]

[image]

**Note 1:** concerning screenshot scatterplot + contour plot: in the scatter plot always one line is visible, but it is changing from step to step. In the contour plot one dot after the other appears.

**Note 2:** this is NOT an assignment request! **I only want to learn plotting in `Octave`** and want to combine this with learning how gradient descent "really" works.

Thanks a million to everyone who provide some code help!

Comment: You mention Octave a lot - but tag the question `matplotlib`, which is a Python library (for plotting).  If you really do mean Octave, you should re-tag the question to octave and remove matplotlib

Comment: Yes, **Andrew is an excellent lecturer on this ML course**. Enjoy the ride! With Octave, check all the ploting tutorials for MATLAB, these will help you progress forward.

Comment: Ah ... sorry for the wrong tagging - i really do mean octacve.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`hold all`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Manipulation-of-Plot-Windows.html#XREFhold) (or just `hold on`, but the color incrementation will not be automatic)
[`ColorOrder`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Axes-Properties.html#index-axes-colororder) is an axis property that can be made default for subsequent figure axes, as partly described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Managing-Default-Properties.html#index-default-graphics-properties).

```
# start with a blank page
clf

# the curve (full line, blue)
x = -5:0.1:10;
y = x.^2;
plot(x, y, '-b')

# successive colors for the points
N_colors = 6;
colororder_map = cool(N_colors);
set(gcf, 'defaultaxesColorOrder', colororder_map)

# this will add the following plots, instead of replacing the old one
hold all
# note: "hold on" does the same, except the colors are not incremented

# the progression
x_p = [10, 7, 3, 1, 0];
y_p = x_p .^2;

# plot the progression
for cpt = 1:numel(x_p)
    x_current = x_p(cpt);
    y_current = y_p(cpt);
    plot(x_current, y_current, 'o')
    pause
endfor
```

[image: sample plot]

Comment: Sorry for late response, I was ill. Will try out your code - thanks a million!

Comment: What version of Octave are you using? I can't getting working on https://saturnapi.com/fullstack/plotting-a-cost-function

Comment: @FullStack The script runs fine under octave 3.8.2 and 4.0.0, both with native graphics or gnuplot. But it is the `pause` command that yields the failure on saturnapi. Just comment out the `pause` and the graph appears fine.

Comment: Why did you used `pause` at all? Seems unnecessary. Anyway, it works for me now. Thanks!

Comment: @FullStack Because the OP asked for a "step by step" plot. But it is right that the colormap already encodes the progression.